# $R_P\cong \mathbb{R}[x]_{(x-1)}$

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

Let $R=\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(xy)$ and $P\subset R$ be the ideal generated by $x-1$. Show that

$$R_P\cong \mathbb{R}[x]_{(x-1)},$$

where $R_P$ is the localization of $R$ at $R\setminus P$ (since $R/P$ is a field, $P$ is maximal, hence prime) and $\mathbb{R}[x]_{(x-1)}$ is the localization of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ at $\{(x-1)^n:n\geq 1\}$.

Now, the proof starts as: $y\in P$, since $-y=xy-y=(x-1)y$, but $x\not\in P$.
Thus $R_P\cong (R/y)/(P/y)$. I don't really get this. I guess, before this we have $R_P\cong R/P$ but **I can't find an isomorphism**. The proof continues.

$R/y$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}[x]$ and $P/y$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}[x](x-1)$.

Hence, $$R_P\cong \mathbb{R}[x]/\mathbb{R}[x](x-1)\cong \mathbb{R}[x]_{(x-1)}.$$
But I also **don't understand this last isomorphism**. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: $x\not \in P$ (since $x=1$ in $R/(y,x-1)\cong \Bbb{R}$) so $x$ is a unit in $R_P$ so $xy=0$ gives $y=0$, whence you can look at $R/(y)=\Bbb{R}[x]$ localized at the prime ideal $(x-1)$

Comment: May I ask you to clarify a couple of things: why is it that $x\not\in P$ and why does that imply $x$ a unit in $R_P$; moreover, how do I exactly get $R_P\cong \mathbb{R}[x]_{(x-1)}$?

Comment: You are wrong: $\mathbb R[x]_{(x-1)}$ is the localization of $\mathbb R[x]$ at the prime ideal $(x-1)$. (I think @reuns already told you this.)

Answer (score 1):

A bad habit (especially when one works with quotient rings of polynomial rings) is to denote the indeterminates by small letters. So, let us write $R=K[X,Y]/(XY)$ as it should be. (Here $K$ is an arbitrary field.) Denote the residue classes of $X$ and $Y$ by $x$ and $y$, and thus $R=K[x,y]$. In this ring one considers the *maximal* ideal $P=(x-1)$. (In order to show that $P$ is maximal we consider $R/P=K[x,y]/(x-1)=\frac{K[X,Y]/(XY)}{(X-1,XY)/(XY)}$ which is isomorphic to $K[X,Y]/(X-1,XY)$. It is not hard to show that the later is isomorphic to $K$.)

Now come back to the main question: in fact, $R_P=K[x,y]_{(x-1)}$ is  $(K[X,Y]/(XY))_{(X-1,XY)/(XY)}$, which at its turn is isomorphic to $K[X,Y]_{(X-1,XY)}/(XY)K[X,Y]_{(X-1,XY)}$. But $(XY)K[X,Y]_{(X-1,XY)}=(Y)K[X,Y]_{(X-1,XY)}$ since $X\notin(X-1,XY)$. Therefore we get $R_P\simeq K[X,Y]_{(X-1,XY)}/(Y)K[X,Y]_{(X-1,XY)}\simeq K[X]_{(X-1)}$.

Comment: I'm curious why you call this a "bad habit". Is it because of the potential confusion with rings of the form $A[b_1, \ldots, b_n] \subseteq B$? Or maybe to reserve lower case letters for the generators of $A[x_1, \ldots, x_n] = A[X_1, \ldots, X_n] \big / I$? I've personally never gotten confused, but I see how someone new to the subject could be. I'm curious if there's other reasons I'm not familiar with, though, since I've never heard before that one _should_ use capital letters for indeterminates

Comment: You provided two good reasons. And yes, it's very confusing to denote the indeterminates and their residue classes by the same letters. (In many old algebra textbooks the indeterminates were denoted by capital letters.)